# send a request for every second in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch

How can I do a fetch request for every second until the res.readyToShow === true in react. If res.status is true, then stop the request.

I want to send a request for every second to verify if readyToShow is true. I can't use socket or webhooks.

```js
 test = (ossUrn, md5Checksum) => setTimeout (() => {
    fetch(
      `google/isReadyToShow`,{
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        urn: ossUrn,
        md5Checksum: md5Checksum,
      }),
    })
    .then((response) => {
      response.json().then((res) => {
          console.log('response ', res);
          return (res.readyToShow)  ? 0 : this.test(ossUrn, md5Checksum);
        });
    })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('err ', err);
      });
  } , 2.5 * 1000);
```

```js
return fetch(
          `google/translation`,
          {
            headers: {
              'X-ACCESS-TOKEN-APP' : accessTokenApp,
              'X-DRIVE-ID': e.itemData.id,
              'X-FILE-NAME': e.itemData.name,
              'X-FILE-TYPE': e.itemData.mimeType,
              'X-FILE-MD5': e.itemData.md5Checksum,
            },
          }
        )
        .then((response) => {
            console.log("google item of id clicked " + e.itemData.id);
            response.json().then((res) => {
              console.log('response ', res);
              md5Checksum = e.itemData.md5Checksum;
              ossUrn =  res.urn;
              console.log('URN ', ossUrn)
              console.log('URL', res);
              console.log('MD5', md5Checksum);
              // execute the function to check if the file is ready to be shown
              this.test(ossUrn, md5Checksum);
            })         
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
              });
        }).catch(() => { throw new Error('Data Loading Error'); });
      
    }
```

I try with this code, but I've this error :

```bash
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'test')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setInterval` with a variable or state that determines wheter the interval should keep on, or if you should call a `clearInterval` because you've got the result you wanted. Something like:

```
function myIntervalFunction() {
   fetch(/*your fetch code*/).then(res => {
      if(res.readyToShow) {
         // setState, or change a let variable to true
      }
   })
}

const myInterval = setInterval(myIntervalFunction, 1000) // executes every 1s
// if you're doing it inside a component use state, if outside use a let that starts with false
if(myState || myLetVar === true) { // got what you wanted
  clearInterval(myInterval) // stops interval
}
```